# catch undefined method exception from a thread and restart it in ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading, exception, activemq-classic, stomp

I have an activemq topic subscriber in ruby which uses stomp protocol with failover to connect to the broker and if somehow the activemq gets restarted then sometimes i get an exception :

```
undefined method `command' for nil:NilClass
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/stomp-1.1.8/lib/stomp/client.rb:295:in `start_listeners'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/stomp-1.1.8/lib/stomp/client.rb:108:in `join'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/stomp-1.1.8/lib/stomp/client.rb:108:in `join'
./lib/active_mq_topic_reader.rb:31:in `active_mq_topic_reader'
main.rb:164
main.rb:163:in `initialize'    
main.rb:163:in `new'
```

but i get this exception only when i use join() method on the broker thread, otherwise no exception appears and the subscriber get unsubscribed from the topic.
The problem which i am facing is i have a different mechanism of shutting down the process by sending shutdown signal, and till then the process waits, but if we use join() then the process will get stuck on this line and i will not be able to close the method by shutdown signal.So what should i do to catch the exception and restart the listener thread?

active_mq_topic_reader.rb :

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'ffi-rzmq'
require 'msgpack'
require 'zmq_helper'
require 'stomp'

include ZmqHelper

def active_mq_topic_reader(context, notice_agg_fe_url, signal_pub_url, monitor_url, active_mq_broker, topic)
  begin
    sender = create_connect_socket(context, ZMQ::PUSH, notice_agg_fe_url)
    monitor = create_connect_socket(context, ZMQ::PUSH, monitor_url)
    active_mq_broker.subscribe(topic, {}) do |msg|
        notice = {}
        ["entity_id","entity_type","system_name","change_type"].each do |key|
            notice[key] = msg.headers[key].to_s
        end
    monitor.send_string("qreader-#{topic.slice(7..-1)}")
    sender.send_string(notice.to_msgpack)
    end
active_mq_broker.join()  #cannot use this
    signal_subscriber.recv_string() #here the code waits for shutdown signal in case of process shutdown
    sender.close()
    monitor.close()
    signal_subscriber.close()
    active_mq_broker.unsubscribe(topic)
    return
  rescue Exception => e
    puts "#{topic}: #{e}"
    puts e.backtrace
    $stdout.flush
  end
end
```

main.rb :

```
context = ZMQ::Context.new(1)
active_mq_broker_audit = Stomp::Client.new("failover:(stomp://localhost:61613,stomp://localhost:61613)")
new_thread = Thread.new do
  active_mq_topic_reader(context,
                         "inproc://notice_agg_fe",
                         "inproc://signal_pub",
                         "tcp://localhost:xxxx",
                         active_mq_broker_audit,
                         "/topic/myTopic")
end
new_thread.join()
```

Comment: There is no point in catching `NoMethodError` exception being sent to `nil`. The error signalizes an error in logic or unhandled case which should be simply fixed. I don't have a crystal ball, but there seems to be a flaw in `active_mq_topic_reader` method or even in main.rb in `initialize` method.

Comment: the thing is, a listener thread is created in client.rb which listens to the topic of activemq but sometimes if activemq goes down then a nil message is sent to the subscriber and when the "command" method is called in client.rb this exception is thrown, so how can i handle this nil value?

Comment: I'm sorry but this is quite unclear, without particular code of `main.rb` and `active_mq_topic_reader` being shown. I'm not saying there can't be a bug in `stomp` module, but you may also improperly initialize/handle it. Without enough information, the question can't be properly answered.

Comment: i have added both the files for a clear picture @DavidUnric

Comment: @DavidUnric is the information enough ??